# How do I keep the <video> and the <canvas> duplicate at same frame?

Tags: javascript, html, video, canvas

I have the following code setup to display the canvas duplicate of the video when paused so it can display a greyscale version of the paused image. As you'll notice the paused frame is always behind the video.

I've tried setting pixelScan() to only happen when the video is paused or ended, and I've experimented with the setTimeout() and requestAnimationFrame() all with no luck. But, that's most likely due to my own lack of skill with JavaScript haha

I just seem to keep getting caught up with this issue and I know there has to be plenty fixes to this simple issue

http://coreytegeler.com/ethan/

```
var processes={
  timerCallback:function() {
    if (this.v2.paused || this.v2.ended) {
      return;
    }
        this.ctxIn.drawImage(this.v2,0,0,this.width,this.height);
        this.pixelScan();
        var self=this;
  },
  doLoad:function(){
    this.v2=document.getElementById("video");
    this.cIn=document.getElementById("cIn");
    this.ctxIn=this.cIn.getContext("2d");
    this.cOut=document.getElementById("cOut");
    this.ctxOut=this.cOut.getContext("2d");
    var self=this;
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.timerCallback();
    }, 34);

    this.v2.addEventListener("playing", function() {
      self.width=v.videoWidth;
      self.height=v.videoHeight;
      cIn.width=v.videoWidth;
      cIn.height=v.videoHeight;
      cOut.width=v.videoWidth;
      cOut.height=v.videoHeight;
      self.timerCallback();
    }, false);

  this.v2.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    openInfo();
    v2.pause();
    v2.loop = true;
    stateAnimate.animate({path: playBtn, fill:"white"}, 300, "ease-in-out");
    loopAnimate.animate({path: loopOn, fill:"white"}, 200, "back-in");
  });
  },
   pixelScan: function() {
    var frame = this.ctxIn.getImageData(0,0,this.width,this.height);
    for(var i=0; i<frame.data.length;i+=4) {
      var grayscale=frame.data[i]*.3+frame.data[i+1]*.59+frame.data[i+2]*.11;
      frame.data[i]=grayscale;
      frame.data[i+1]=grayscale;
      frame.data[i+2]=grayscale;
    }
    this.ctxOut.putImageData(frame,0,0);
    return;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you isolate your code into a working demo on JSFiddle? That way it's easily editable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pause` event:

```
this.v2.addEventListener('pause', function() {
    // process frame here
}, false);
```